# Google sheets cannot coerce string to value

Tags: javascript, parsing, google-apps-script, google-sheets, return-value

I have an issue.

I am using this formula:

```
      function import2(url) {
        var html, content = "";
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

        if (response) {
          html = response.getContentText();

          if (html)
            content = html.match(
              /<td class="line text">\s*EUR\s+(\d[\d,]*)<\/td>/)[1];
          // Logger.log(content);
          parseFloat(content);
        }
        return content; //Number
      }
```

It can only import values from the following website: [Stock price](https://www.morningstar.nl/nl/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F00000QIPC) (https://www.morningstar.nl/nl/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F00000QIPC)

When using the this for url it returns: `20,05`, however this cannot be coerced to a number to make calculations with it. Can anybody help me understand why this is?

I also tried:

```
      function import2(url) {
        var html, content = "";
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

        if (response) {
          html = response.getContentText();

          if (html)
            content = html.match(
              /<td class="line text">\s*EUR\s+(\d[\d,]*)<\/td>/)[1];
          // Logger.log(content);
          parseFloat(content);
        }
        return Number(content); //<-- changed
      }
```

The last return value is changed to `Number()`. With this code it gives an error right away and says the returned value is not a number.

I think the issue might be with `\s*EUR\s+(\d[\d,]*)` But I am unsure if this is the case

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

As a simple modification, how about replacing `,` to `.` for your below script using `replace()`? By this, `20,05` is returned as the number of `20.05`.

#### Modified script:

```
function import2(url) {
  var html, content = "";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

  if (response) {
    html = response.getContentText();

    if (html)
      content = html.match(
        /<td class="line text">\s*EUR\s+(\d[\d,]*)<\/td>/)[1].replace(",", ".");  // <--- Modified
    // Logger.log(content);
    parseFloat(content);
  }
  return Number(content); //<-- changed
}
```

#### Note:

- When you want to use `20,05` to `2005`, please modify `replace(",", ".")` to `replace(",", "")`.

#### Reference:

- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)